# Edits being denied and copied as own edition

Tags: discussion

I edited a question with much mistakes, and the post owner(a 1-reputation user) simply rejected my suggestion and edit the post himself. I didn't lost any reputation, but at least when people peer-review my edits they will find a rejected record...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to link to the incident.

In [this case](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/364553), however, it seems your edit was simply displaced by a much larger edit. It was automatically rejected by the system, not the user.

Comment: Yup, that's what happens when two people are editing at the same time.

Comment: Yup, like when @Rinzwind is logged on! ;-)